# Change event to worksheet with exceptions

Tags: vba, events

I placed for example 3 option buttons that that will copy from some range and paste into the region of my interest, what I need to do is when user manually changes the cell from the region of my interest I need to switch the option button to another one, let's say "Option Button 4" while turning off all three other option buttons.

It worked great with "Change event" function however the problem arises when I go back to three other option buttons that I initially coded to copy and paste into the range. It will turn the option button 4 on after copying and pasting into the region, meaning its recognizing as part of the worksheet change so that "Change event" part of the macro triggers.

So I was trying to give an exception to this Change event function which in this case is when it's formula copied from other cells, but I don't seem to find any solutions as of yet.

I'm not sure if I've explained enough but if anyone knows any tip/ more explanation please let me know!

Thank you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Dim target As Range
    Set target = Range("L15:P15")

   If Not Intersect(target, Range("L15:P15")) Is Nothing Then

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option Button 174").ControlFormat.Value = 1

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For the macros that the option buttons are attached to, you can add:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False

    ... copy and paste data here ....

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

This will bypass the Worksheet_Change event

Comment: Thanks, I tried but the sub routine for the macro attached to the option buttons end after enableEvents are turned true, meaning change event still occurs after the sub-routine. If I leave it without turning back to true, change event does not even trigger at all.